# Read dbf with arcpy in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, arcgis, arcpy

I have exported an **ArcGIS Desktop 10.7 table** into a **dbf** file.
Now I want to do some GIS calculation in standalone Python.
Therefore I have started a **PyCharm** project referencing the ArcGIS Python interpreter and hence am able to import **arcpy** into my **main.py**.
Problem is: I don't want to pip install other modules, but I don't know how to correctly read the dbf table with arcpy.

```
#encoding=utf-8 
import arcpy
path=r"D:\test.dbf"
sc=arcpy.SearchCursor(path) # Does not work: IOError exception str() failed
tv=arcpy.mapping.TableView(path) # Does not work either: StandaloneObject invalid data source or table
```

The dbf file is correct, it can be read into ArcGIS.
Can someone please give me an idea, how to read the file standalone with **arcpy**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using `pandas`

Python from ArcMap comes with some modules. You can load the data into a pandas.DataFrame and work with this format. Pandas is well-documented and there is a lot of already asked question about it all over the web. It's also super easy to do groupby or table manipulations.

```py
import pandas as pd
import arcpy


def read_arcpy_table(self, table, fields='*', null_value=None):
    """
    Transform a table from ArcMap into a pandas.DataFrame object

    table : Path the table
    fields : Fields to load - '*' loads all fields
    null_value : choose a value to replace null values
    """
    fields_type = {f.name: f.type for f in arcpy.ListFields(table)}
    if fields == '*':
        fields = fields_type.keys()
    fields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(table) if f.name in fields]
    fields = [f for f in fields if f in fields_type and fields_type[f] != 'Geometry'] # Remove Geometry field if FeatureClass to avoid bug

    # Transform in pd.Dataframe
    np_array = arcpy.da.FeatureClassToNumPyArray(in_table=table,
                                                 field_names=fields,
                                                 skip_nulls=False,
                                                 null_value=null_value)
    df = self.DataFrame(np_array)
    return df
# Add the function into the loaded pandas module
pd.read_arcpy_table = types.MethodType(read_arcpy_table, pd)

df = pd.read_arcpy_table(table='path_to_your_table')
# Do whatever calculations need to be done
```

## Using cursor

You can also use arcpy cursors and `dict` for simple calculation.

There are simple example on this page on how to use correctly cursors :
https://desktop.arcgis.com/fr/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/searchcursor-class.htm

Answer (score 0):

My bad,
after reading the **Using cursor** approach, I figured out that using the

```
sc=arcpy.SearchCursor(path) # Does not work: IOError exception str() failed
```

approach was correct, but at the time around 3 AM, I was a little bit exhausted and missed the **typo in the path** that caused the error. Nevertheless, a more descriptive error message e.g. `IOError could not open file` rather than `IOError exception str() failed` would have solved my mistake as acrGIS newbie.. : /